# iframe contentWindow is undefined when use window.frames[name] to access

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

If use following way to get the contentWindow, the value is undefined

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>iframe test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <iframe id="frame1" src="frame1.html" name="frame1"></iframe>
<script>
    document.body.onload = function() {
        console.info("index loaded");
        var frame1 = window.frames["frame1"];
        console.info(frame1.contentWindow);
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

If use the other way like following, it works fine:

```
var frame1 = document.getElementById("frame1");
console.info(frame1.contentWindow);
```

I tested on FF 29.0.1, chrome 34， IE11, they all work the same way.

So I have two questions:

1. why the first way can't get contentWindow value
2. iframe.contentWindow is compatible in all browser?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
window.frames["frame1"];
```

is the `contentWindow`, it gets a named window, and in your case it's the same thing as

```
document.getElementById("frame1").contentWindow
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/ChB6f/4/)

Comment: so contentWindow is compatible in all browsers includes IE8+?

Comment: Should be pretty cross browser, some browser used to use contentDocument, but I think contentWindow works everywhere today.